# Como contar os registros de um csv em python?

Tags: python, lista, csv

Sou iniciante em Python e estou com uma dificuldade.

Tenho uma base de dados CSV separado por ";" com 6 colunas. 
Eu gostaria de contar quantos registros têm, cujo o sexo é "Feminino".
Vocês podem me indicar como fazer ou por onde devo começar meus estudos?

Abaixo está o código que tenho até agora.

```
import csv
with open('teste.csv', 'r') as arquivo:
delimitador = csv.Sniffer().sniff(arquivo.read(1024), delimiters=";")
arquivo.seek(0)
leitor = csv.reader(arquivo, delimitador)
dados = list(leitor)
for x in dados:
    print(x)
```

Converti em lista, mas não consegui pensar em uma forma de verificar se há "Feminino" na linha.

Qualquer dica para iniciante também será bem vinda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para contar as linhas/listas que têm "Feminino", podes fazer assim:

```
import csv

l_feminino = []
with open('teste.csv', 'r') as arquivo:
    delimitador = csv.Sniffer().sniff(arquivo.read(1024), delimiters=";")
    arquivo.seek(0)
    leitor = csv.reader(arquivo, delimitador)
    dados = list(leitor)
for x in dados:
    if('Feminino' in x): # se existir 'Feminino'
        l_feminino.append(x) # vamos armazenar o registo

print(l_feminino) # todos os registos que tem "Feminino"
print(len(l_feminino)) # quantos registos que tem "Feminino"
```

Sinceramente nem precisas de importar nenhum modulo para isto, se for só isto mesmo podes só:

```
dados = []
with open('teste.csv') as arquivo:
    lines = arquivo.read().split()
cols = lines.pop(0).split(';')
dados = [i.split(';') for i in lines]
dados_f = [i for i in dados if "Feminino" in i]
print(cols) # colunas
print(dados) # todos os registos
print(dados_f) # registos femininos
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Por agora, só if "Feminino" dentro do for já me atende, é um algoritmo simples. Vlw

Comment: De nada @MatheusMacedo, se resolveu podes aceitar a resposta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 0):

Para se obter a contagem de linhas que possuem a ocorrência "Feminino" em um determinado arquivo, você pode fazer algo como:

```
nlinhas = 0

with open('teste.csv') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        if "Feminino" in linha:
            nlinhas += 1

print(nlinhas)
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
nlinhas = sum( 1 for line in open('teste.csv') if "Feminino" in line )
print(nlinhas)
```

Comment: Vlw, cara. Funcionou aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Nao precisa iterar sobre as linhas do CSV. Voce pode conseguir o que precisa usando [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

print(len(df[df['Sexo'] == "Feminino"].index))
```

Explicando:

Retorna uma Lista com True e False para todas as linhas que atendem a condicao

```
df['Sexo'] == "Feminino"
```

Quando colocada dentro do proprio df, voce esta "cortando" o dataframe so com as linhas que atendem a condicao:

```
df[df['Sexo'] == "Feminino"]
```

Depois o [len()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) te da o numero de linhas.

Outra forma de atingir o mesmo objetivo eh usando o [shape](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html):

```
print(df[df['Sexo'] == "Feminino"].shape[0])
```

Shape é uma tupla que:

- `shape[0]` retorna a quantidade de linhas
- `shape[1]` retorna a quantidade de colunas